# React CSSTransitionGroup doesn't add leave classes

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

I have a component that gets unmounted after ten seconds, and I just can't seem to get the leave-animations working with React CSSTransitionGroup. The appear classes gets added when the component mounts and those animations work well. However, the leave classes never gets added to the component on unmount. I've found several working jsfiddle examples, but the code doesn't work for me. I'm new to React so I'm hoping that someone can point me in the right direction. I've set the timeouts to be able to see if the classes gets added.

Main component:

```
this.state = {
renderBlankSlate: true,
//the rest of the initial state..
}

// This unmounts the component
componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setTimeout(() => this.setState({renderBlankSlate: false}), 10000);
}

{ this.state.renderBlankSlate ? 
                <ReactCSSTransisionGroup 
                    component="div"
                    transitionName="slide"
                    transitionEnterTimeout={ 500 } 
                    transitionAppear={ true }
                    transitionAppearTimeout={ 2000 }
                    transitionLeaveTimeout={ 5000 }
                >
                    <BlankSlate />
                </ReactCSSTransisionGroup>
                 : null }
```

CSS:

```
.slide-appear {
transform: translateX(110%);
height: 0;
opacity: 0;
}
.slide-appear.slide-appear-active {
transform: translateX(0);
height: 100%;
opacity: 1;
transition: all 2s ease-in;
}

.slide-leave {
transform: translateX(0);
}
.slide-leave.slide-leave-active {
transform: translateX(110%);
transition: 5s ease-in;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to add that ternary within the transition group.

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup 
  component="div"
  transitionName="slide"
  transitionEnterTimeout={ 500 } 
  transitionAppear={ true }
  transitionAppearTimeout={ 2000 }
  transitionLeaveTimeout={ 5000 }
>
  {this.state.renderBlankSlate ? <BlankSlate /> : null}
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

The reason your leave animation isn't firing is because the Transition group is leaving as well

Comment: Yay! Thank you so much :D